# What is the correct button_to syntax for adding a class to the generated form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, ruby-on-rails-3, helper, actionview

I'm trying to apply a class to the form generated by button_to in Rails 3.

The `:class` option sets the class for the submit button so the [docs](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.1.0/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/button_to) tell us to use `:form_class` to apply a class to the form.

E.g.

```
<%= button_to 'x', user_contact_path(@user, contact), :method => :delete, :form_class => "delete" %>
```

This just adds the attribute `form_class="delete"` to the button element. I've tried various combinations using `:html_options` and so on.

Anybody know how to do this?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

That method works perfectly fine for me. I am able to do:

```
<%= button_to "Hello", root_url, :method => :get, :form_class => "my_class" %>
```

the above generates the following:

```
<form action="http://localhost:3000/" class="my_class" method="get">
  <div><input type="submit" value="Hello"></div>
</form>
```

However, this is in Rails 3.1 as the link in your question points and the same wouldn't work in Rails 3.0.x since the [form class is hard coded](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/e3dd2107c57a8efaaea5d61cf8da65f7444760b2/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/url_helper.rb#L302).

From url_helper code:

```
("<form method=\"#{form_method}\" action=\"#{html_escape(url)}\" 
  #{"data-remote=\"true\"" if remote} class=\"button_to\"><div>" +
  method_tag + tag("input", html_options) + request_token_tag + 
  "</div></form>"
).html_safe
```

Comment: Thanks Syed, quite right - it is hard coded as I'm using 3.0.7 I think.

Comment: I actually didn't know this before today. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
<%= button_to 'x', user_contact_path(@user, contact), {:method => :delete, :form_class => "delete"} %>
```

This forces `:form_class => "delete"` to be part of the `options` hash instead of the `html_options` hash.

Comment: Hmn, this syntax doesn't work for me. Must be something to do with my version of rails.